# How to best represent a plea deal during a job search

Tags: interviewing, new-job, hiring-process, human-resources, hiring

Long ago I made a poor decision to drive after drinking after being at a birthday party. I was pulled over, arrested and charged with Operating While Intoxicated (OWI).

My charge was later reduced to Operating While Visibly Impaired (OWVI) as plea deal that I pled guilty to and was convicted of.

So when answering the question of “do you have a criminal record, if so, what is it?” Whether it’s on a job application and or during a phone interview what am I supposed to put/say?

For example, do I have to tell the whole story of being charged with an OWI first and then having it reduced to an OWVI or would I just need to put down/say what I was convicted of, which is the OWVI.

I just don’t want to misstep here and lose an opportunity.

Comment: What is your legal jurisdiction? That may affect what they can ask and how much you are obliged to say.

Comment: Look into if you can have your record expunged,  Then you will have no record.

Comment: How long ago was 'long ago'? Check in your jurisdiction for how long before this conviction is spent. e.g in Michigan, an OWVI is spent after seven years (it's a misdemeanor). After seven years, it would be automatically sealed.

Comment: "Do you have a criminal record, if so, what is it?" - You answer the question in the affirmative; Since you were charged and convicted of a crime.

Comment: @PeteCon What do you mean by spent exactly? I was under the impression that OWVI's stayed on the record forever, unless expunged after the waiting period in MI.

Answer (score 20):

You plead guilty to crime A.  Why would you even mention crime B, a bigger crime?  They're not asking what crimes have you ever been accused of, it's what crimes were you convicted of.  That's the one you were convicted of.  That's all you tell them about.

I'd also look into your local laws to see if you have to tell them anything, there's locations they can't ask those types of questions.  But why would you tell them that a crime may have been worse?

If asked about it, be honest and explain that you made a stupid mistake you will never repeat.  But a chance to explain is a chance to negate what happened and make yourself look good.  You wouldn't bring up something worse.  If I was in a fatal accident and plead to reckless driving I wouldn't tell them "luckily they didn't decide to charge me with vehicular manslaughter".

Answer (score 3):

**On the application**, keep it simple.  If you were convicted of OWVI, write "OWVI", the state/jurisdiction, and the approximate date.  If it doesn't ask you on the application to explain, DON'T EXPLAIN.  Provide the minimum amount of information, because that's the same amount of information that's going to come up if the company does a standard background check.

**With HR or during an interview**, again, keep it simple.  If you're asked what happened, say "I made a bad judgment call, and ended up paying the price for it."  Nine times out of ten, they won't care about the details as long as you acknowledge the mistake you made and express remorse.  Answer *specific* questions with *specific* answers, and do not volunteer more information than you are asked.

Someone here has also suggested you look into an expungement.  That probably won't happen fast, but it can make your life easier if you can do it.

(I am not an attorney, and this does not constitute legal advice.)

Answer (score 1):

This is all anecdotal and I don't really care to elaborate but...

Just be as upfront as possible and say you made a mistake.  They won't really care about what the final conviction was.  This will most likely be with an HR person and not the primary interviewer.  Expect a drug test even if the company doesn't normally drug test.  It's not as big of a deal as you would think.

Comment: I just want to ensure that I am saying the correct thing when they ask or when I have to fill out an application. 

I don’t want to over-tell the story by saying I was charged with an OWI but then reduced to an OWVI as a conviction if I don’t have to. 

I’d rather just say what is required.

Comment: @AccomplishedHall this could be a jurisdiction thing as others have mentioned.  I'm not sure I've seen this asked on an application.  It was something that came up during the background check and HR addressed it in their portion of the interview.

Comment: @Steve it is very much a jurisdiction thing. I know in my state it was a common question on job applications until the state passed a law to ban it. Other states will have different practices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's even legal to ask about a misdemeanor charge where you work: **Keep your answer simple and short.**

The last thing you want to do is spend a lot of time on this topic. A good answer might be something like this: "Oh, several years ago, when I was young and foolish, I got an impaired driving charge. Nowadays I'd never do something like that."

As someone who has hired dozens of people, OWI's are so common that unless it was recent, I wouldn't even bother asking about it. But if you are asked, just answer briefly and move on. You want to allay any concerns about your *current* suitability for the position, not make this a memorable part of the interview.